# How to exclude subdirectories in the destination while using /mir /xd switch in robocopy

Tags: robocopy

There is a script running which mirrors a bunch of folders from one volume to another. The problem is that now there are going to be subdirectories within those folders at the destination which are not part of the original mirroring script. They are standalone subdirectories and I don't want them purged once the mirroring kicks in. Is there a way for me to use the `/xd` switch in robocopy wherein I'd be able to exclude the destination subdirectories.

Example:

```
robocopy "\\hq04t2fis202\archive\dr" "\\hq04t3fis202\archive\dr" /mir /xd "\\hq04t3fis202\archive\dr\*\hq04s2dba301"
```

In the above example, there are several directories under `\\hq04t2fis202\archive\dr` that are being mirrored. And at the destination, once these directories are mirrored from the source, there is another script which dumps separate subdirectories within each of those directories. So what I want to do is somehow use the /xd switch to avoid purging those subdirectories at the destination. 
Also, in the above example, in the `/xd` switch, I'm using the `"*"` wildcard to mean that I want to include all the directories that fall under the `"\\hq04t3fis202\archive\dr"` root folder at the destination.

Need help and suggestions as to whether this is possible, and if it is then how can I do it. So far I've tried and tested many other switches like `/xo`, `/xx`, but none of them solve my purpose.
Also, `/xx` would work except that now it won't delete any folders at the destination at all and it wouldn't be mirroring.

Hopefully I'm not overly confusing everyone here. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 39):

When i tried the solution with /XD i found, that the path to exclude should be the source path - not the destination.

e.g. this Works

```
robocopy c:\test\a c:\test\b /MIR /XD c:\test\a\leavethisdiralone\
```

Comment: when I had a relative path after /xd, the directory was not excluded.  Making it an absolute path corrected the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: what if I use robocopy like this `robocopy mysrc/ mydest/ /MIR /XD logs /XD tomcat/temp,` - will the specified directories be excluded or do I have to prepend the mysrc/ folder for the /XD?

Comment: Actually @Manticore , after the XD you don't have to write the entire source path. If you exclude a foldername, Robocopy will ignore all instances of this folder. You can use this to you benefit if you have the same folder (e.g. a temp folder) many places in the folder structure.

Comment: to use relative path in /XD try:
    %cd%\relative\path\xxx

Comment: When you copy Users folder in Windows you can get Application data loop. Use /XJ to avoid this

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that even though we add a folder to skip list it will be deleted if it does not exist.

**The solution is to add both the destination and the source folder with full path.**

I will try to explain the different scenarios and what happens below, based on my experience.

**Starting folder structure:**

```
d:\Temp\source\1.txt
d:\Temp\source\2\2.txt
```

**Command:**

```
robocopy D:\Temp\source D:\Temp\dest /MIR
```

This will copy over all the files and folders that are missing and deletes all the files and folders that cannot be found in the source

Let's add a new folder and then add it to the command to skip it.

**New structure:**

```
d:\Temp\source\1.txt
d:\Temp\source\2\2.txt
d:\Temp\source\3\3.txt
```

**Command:**

```
robocopy D:\Temp\source D:\Temp\dest /MIR /XD "D:\Temp\source\3"
```

If I add /XD with the source folder and run the command it all seems good the command it wont copy it over.

**Now add a folder to the destination to get this setup:**

```
d:\Temp\source\1.txt
d:\Temp\source\2\2.txt
d:\Temp\source\3\3.txt

d:\Temp\dest\1.txt
d:\Temp\dest\2\2.txt
d:\Temp\dest\3\4.txt
```

If I run the command it is still fine, 4.txt stays there 3.txt is not copied over. All is fine.

But, **if I delete the source** folder "d:\Temp\source\3" **then the destination folder and the file are deleted** even though it is on the skip list

```
                       1    D:\Temp\source\
    *EXTRA Dir        -1    D:\Temp\dest\3\
      *EXTRA File                  4        4.txt
                       1    D:\Temp\source\2\
```

If I change the command to skip the destination folder instead then the folder is not deleted, when the folder is missing from the source.

```
robocopy D:\Temp\source D:\Temp\dest /MIR /XD "D:\Temp\dest\3"
```

On the other hand if the folder exists and there are files it will copy them over and delete them:

```
                       1    D:\Temp\source\3\
          *EXTRA File                  4        4.txt
100%        New File                   4        3.txt
```

**To make sure the folder is always skipped and no files are copied over even if the source or destination folder is missing we have to add both to the skip list:**

```
robocopy D:\Temp\source D:\Temp\dest /MIR /XD "d:\Temp\source\3" "D:\Temp\dest\3"
```

After this no matters if the source folder is missing or the destination folder is missing, robocopy will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than creating empty directories in source to exclude, you can supply the full destination path to the /XD switch to have the destination directories untouched

```
robocopy "%SOURCE_PATH%" "%DEST_PATH%" /MIR /XD "%DEST_PATH%"\hq04s2dba301
```

Comment: This can also be used with other switches that accept a path argument, such as /XF

Comment: Using /E and /PURGE is the same as using /MIR

Comment: /XD [relative_path_to_folder] /MIR does the job

Comment: I find this doesn't work - see Lars Meldgard answer.  /XD requires full *source* path and not destination path.

Answer (score 6):

The way you can exclude a destination directory while using the /mir is by making sure the destination directory also exists on the source. I went into my source drive and created blank directories with the same name as on the destination, and then added that directory name to the /xd. It successfully mirrored everything while excluding the directory on the source, thereby leaving the directory on the destination intact.

Comment: I can verify that this is true. This is the only solution when you are trying to exclude a specific directory nested several layers deeper than what exists on your source.

Comment: An addition...  If the target directory exists then use the full path to the *target* folder in /XD.  If the target directory does *not* exist then use the full path to the *source* folder in the /XD.

Comment: Its not necessary to create blank destinations IME. If you remove the trailing slashs from the paths, you can use XD with /MIR on source path. For example: robocopy E:\backup C:\backup /MIR /XD "G:\BACKUP\EXCLUDE" will mirror the directory, while excluding the G:\BACKUP\EXCLUDE folder.

Answer (score 4):

The argument order seems to matter... to exclude subdirectories, I used

```
robocopy \\source\folder C:\destinationfolder /XD * /MIR
```

...and that works for me (Windows 10 copy from Windows Server 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Try my way :

> robocopy.exe "Desktop\Test folder 1" "Desktop\Test folder 2" /XD "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Test folder 2\XXX dont touch" /MIR

Had to put `/XD` before `/MIR` while including the full Destination Source directly after `/XD`.