# Looping this batch syntax

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a bunch of folders that I have to move to another directory. To do this task I made a .bat. My intention is to select the folders that I want to move and drag on the .bat file. This is working with the following syntax for one folder at a time, what I have to do if I want to do the same with multiple folders at a time?

BONUS questions, how can I copy only the files that are in the folders without copying the folders itself?

```
xcopy %* C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in\ /s
```

Comment: why don't use robocopy? it has options to include/exclude files/directories https://serverfault.com/q/778763/343888 https://stackoverflow.com/q/14511537/995714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SHIFT` command is what you are looking for.

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    xcopy %1 C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in\ /s
    SHIFT
    GOTO LOOP
)
```

When d&ding several files or folders to your batch script, their paths are being appended as arguments. `%1` is the first path, `%2` is the second one and so on. `SHIFT` does nothing but moving the index to the right so `%2` becomes `%1`, `%3` becomes `%2` and so on. The script keeps on looping until it reaches the last appended path which becomes `%1`. The next execution of `SHIFT` sets `%1` to an empty string, the IF condition is no longer fulfilled and the script stops.

Now let's get to your bonus question:

There are several ways to achieve this. Here one of those:

```
@ECHO OFF
:LOOP
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    FOR /F %%F IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%1"') DO (
        COPY /y %%F C:\DOCUMENTALE\dms_in\
    )
)
```

Comment: I would suggest using **`%1`**, **`%2`** & **`%3`** etc. as opposed to **`%1%`**, **`%2%`** & **`%3%`**.

Comment: @Compo Thx, you are right, this is the correct way. I'll edit my answer. However, %1% works as well.

Comment: @MichaelS because `IF NOT "%1%"==""` will be parsed as 2 separate variables. The first `%1` will be replaced with the first argument, but the next `%` is not followed by any valid variable name, hence the `%` will be stripped off due to [rule 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/995714)